# How should I store multiple relationships (many posts to many categories)?

Tags: database-design, performance

I have posts stored in a `posts` table and I want each post to have multiple categories, what is the most efficient way to store the categories and their relationships ?

I thought of it this way first:

```
Categories Table:

+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(32)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent     | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Relationships Table:

+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| post_id    | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cat_id     | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| order      | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Using this structure I will have lots of rows inside the relationships table, for example if a post has 4 categories I will have 4 rows only for this post, of course I won't have that much categories related to the post but I want to implement the same structure for tags too.

Am I doing it right ? is there a better structure to use ?

Comment: What is the `order` column for? Is it to define "order" (of significance?) to posts of the same category? Or to categories of the same post?

Comment: @ypercube it's to define the categories order for the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that you have described it is the way to do it.  The Primary key for this table is Post_Id, Cat_ID.

Comment: +1 for identifying the problem as many-to-many.  The original title indicated many-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

One-to-many are generally stored with a key in the detail table

Something like:

```
Master-table
============
Id    Name
--    -----
1     Test1
2     Test2

Detail-table
===============
Id MasterId Text
-- -------- -----
1  1        Text1
2  1        Text2
3  2        Text4
4  2        Text5
```

If you have a many-to-many relationship you will need an extra table in between.

Comment: this is a many-to-many relationship. each post has many categories and each category has many posts. he did the relationship table ok (entity B).